# Trouble understand cbw in assembly

Tags: assembly

I have the following example problem:

```
what will be the value of ax after executing these instructions?
mov ax, 2040h
add al, ah
add ah, al
cbw
```

Before the cbw instruction I have `8060h` in ax. As I understand cbw, it sign extends al into the rest of the word, so I thought after cbw, ax would be `FF60h`. After checking the answer, I found it is `0060h`, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sign extends `al`, so it would use the highest  bit in `al` to determine the sign, not the highest bit in `ax`.

As the highest bit in `al` is zero (`60h` = `01100000`), the rest of the word is filled with zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and easy explanation! You correctly assumed exactly how I went wrong, too!